# Issue in google maps embed API with time

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-embed

I trying to implement search for places at particular time with transit mode in google maps with print option. So i used google maps EMBED API. What i achieved is i can search for places with origin and destination parameters in transit mode. What i cannot be able to do is search with specific time. There is no parameter in official documentation given regarding time . For reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start

```
I have used JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pravinkumar/t5kg4gc2/ to replicate this problem. Please someone help me find a solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think both Embed API and Static Maps API does not provide that function.

You can either use the [server side Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/), which has a similar format, to get that info, in additional to your embed api,

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Brooklyn&destination=Queens&departure_time=1343641500&mode=transit&key=API_KEY

or else you should switch to the Javascript API. You should able to do that with the [Transit Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#TransitOptions)

Answer (score 0):

As you note from its absence in the documentation, time-of-travel routing is not a supported feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am aware of that. I need an alternate way to achieve this. Can you help me with this?